# Sending hex via UART from raspberry pi

Tags: python, uart

I have an NRF52 chip connected to my raspberry Pi. I want to send hex files from my raspberry pi to the NRF via UART so I can make a sweet bootloader. I am working on a python script that reads line by line the hex file and sends it over. My issue right now is that a line like :020000040000FA is being sent over as 0x3A, 0x30, 0x32 etc. I do not want to send the ASCII over I want to send the raw data.. so 0x02, 0x00 etc. I want to essentially 0x2 instead of 0x30, 0x32 but do not know how... Can anyone help or give some ideas? 
My python skills are well below par... I have tried to add line[1]+line[2] and encoding it as hex but it just gives 3032... here is my code I have as of right now. any ideas or help would be awesome.

Cheers,

Eric

```
 1 #! /usr/bin/python
 2 import binascii
 3 import time
 4 import serial
 5 import codecs
 6
 7 PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
 8 BAUD_RATE = 9600
 9
 10 print 'opening serial port'
 11 time.sleep(1)
 12 myshit = []
 13 ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)
 14 i = 1
 15 with open("blinkybootloader.hex", "rb") as file:
 16         for line in file:
 18                 for l in line:
 19                         print line[i],
 20
 21                         i+=1
 22                         time.sleep(.5)
 23                 print line
 24                 time.sleep(.1)
 25                 ser.write(myshit)
```

~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly.  But it seems like you want to take each line of text *:XXxxXXxxXX...* and interpret all of the characters past the first one on each line as pairs of hexadecimal characters, then to convert those into strings of bytes which you can then send to your Raspberry Pi over the serial port.

In that case I'd use the regular expression package to "compile" the following regexp:

```
import re
chunk = re.compile('..')
# ... chunk.findall(x) returns a sequence of x broken into 2-character chunks
```

Then after line 16 in your example I'd do something like this:

```
for line in file:
    data = b''.join(chr(int(x, 16)) for x in chunk.findall(line[1:])])
    print data
    ser.write(data)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Notice the trick of chunking the slice of the line into pairs of digits, then converting those from text to integers using the extra (optional) base= argument to the *int()* function, and using the resulting integer as an argument to the built-in *chr()* (convert to character) function.

The **b''** literal syntax for this join is to specify that this is a **byte** string.  That's not particularly important in Python 2.7 (and not even supported before Python 2.7).  You can just use a plain old string for the old versions of Python.  But in Python 3.x you have to use byte strings or *bytearray* objects because Python 3 "strings" are Unicode and must be explicitly encoded and decoded.

Comment: I usually won't use regular expressions for "chunking" a sequence; but it's the most syntactically compact way to do so far chunking a string into small fixed-size substrings like this.

Comment: hi Jim, I do not think I explained, well my bad. I still think you were able to answer my question. I will try this when i get home but for extra clarification. the lay out of the hex file would be some thing like this :020000040000FA;
: = intel format
0x02 = number of data bytes in record
0x0000 = address to store data
0x04 = record type
0x0000 = data
0xFA = check sum.
I want to combine two strings in the object and then send that byte over so instead of 0 and 2 being sent over separately I want to join them and just send 0x02.

Comment: if the first two hex digits (nibbles) are a length, and the next four are an address, and the rest are data then my code might be adjusted around a line decomposition like `lgth, addr, data = line[1:2], line[3:8], line[9:]` ... and then using the variable names `lgth` (no to conflict with the `len()` builtin function), `addr`, and `data`. (This assumes that we're also skipping past the literal : prefixed to each line).

Comment: Hi Jim. The above code produced the desired results. The line decomposition is not super necessary as this is just a test. I am working on an over the air bootloader. First step was get it working over serial and then move to over the air. I just wanted to be able to send a line from the hex file and have my mcu just pick it up and calculate the checksum etc.  I did not really want to do data conversion from ASCII to raw. Thanks so much for your help! (: